# Inserting a parent entity with existing child in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

This is a general question, I'm sure it's quite common, however I haven't found anything on it (or I don't know what to search for I guess).

I'm having the following entities in my project:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int      Id          { get; set; }
    public virtual string   FirstName   { get; set; }
    public virtual string   LastName    { get; set; }
    public virtual Unit     Unit        { get; set; }
}

public class Unit
{
    public virtual int      Id          { get; set;}
    public virtual string   Name        { get; set;}
}
```

This is how I've done the Fluent NHibernate mappings:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("UserId");
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        References(x => x.Unit).Column("UnitId");
    }
}

public class UnitMap : ClassMap<Unit> 
{        
    public UnitMap() 
    {
        Table("Unit");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("UnitId");
        Map(x => x.Name).Column("Name").Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.Users).KeyColumn("UnitId");
    }
}
```

Now here is my question. How do I create a new User if I only have the user's unit Id not a full unit object, and the unit already exists in the database (created previously) ?
Something like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    // Adding a user to a unit example
    public void SavingAUser(int unitId)
    {
        var user = new User
        {
            FirstName = "TestFirstName",
            LastName = "TestLastName",
            Unit = new Unit() // <-- I have only the Id of the unit I don't actually have a unit object here I don't want to query the DB to get the full object, I already have the Id 
        };

        var userRepository = new UserRepository();
        userRepository.Save(user);
    }
}
```

How would I go about something like this. I hope I'm making sense, if not please let me know I'll throw in more clarifications. I'm also pretty certain that this is a very common scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a proxy to the unit without fetching it.

```
    var user = new User
    {
        FirstName = "TestFirstName",
        LastName = "TestLastName",
        Unit = Session.Load<Unit>(unitId)
    }
```

You'll need to expose the session object.